# Renaming a function globally

Tags: ghidra

I have decompiled a DLL, and in the Symbol tree, I have clicked a function.
This function looks like this in the Decompile window:

```
undefined4 process_something(undefined4 param_1,undefined4 param_2)
{
      thunk_FUN_1017e9e0(param_1,param_2);
      return 0;
}
```

I have right-clicked on FUN_1017e9e0, then I selected "Rename Function".
I have renamed it "process_something_internal", and "Namespace" was set to Global.

Now the function looks like this:

```
undefined4 process_something(undefined4 param_1,undefined4 param_2)
{
      process_something_internal1(param_1,param_2);
      return 0;
}
```

However, when I double click "process_something_internal1", it takes me to the function:

```
void FUN_1017e9e0(undefined4 param_1,undefined4 param_2)
{
    //do something
    return;
 }
```

Why has the function not be renamed as well?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You renamed a thunk ("thunk_FUN_1017e9e0").  That thunk points to the function "FUN_1017e9e0".  When you double-click on the thunk, Ghidra is bypassing it and taking you directly to the thunked function.

In the Ghidra symbol table, you should see 2 separate entries for "process_something_internal1" (thunk) and "FUN_1017e9e0" (thunked function).

Comment: this sounds like the correct answer.  The process_something_internal1 vs process_something_internal is semi-puzzling.

Comment: I should've added the following from the "Functions" section in "Ghidra Help":  Within the Code Browser, double-clicking on a thunk function name will navigate to the associated thunked function, while thunked functions will display back-references (i.e., XREFs) to the associated thunk functions with a Ref-Type of 'T'.

Answer (score -1):

This function has already been loaded and therefore it is in memory.
When you override it's name the memory reference is still the same.